# Can you solve this math problem

Tags: calculation-puzzle, pattern

If these are true :

```
5 + 3 = 158
9 + 1 = 910
8 + 6 = 4814
4 + 4 = 168
```

then 7 + 3 = ??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm guessing it's

> 2110

Why?

> Because each number result is generated by appending the multiplication of the two numbers and their addition.

Or more elaborately:

> $$\begin{align}5 + 3 = 15\ 8 = 5 \times 3 &\mid 5 + 3\\9 + 1 = 9\ 10 = 9 \times 1 &\mid 9 + 10\\8 + 6 = 48\ 14 = 8 \times 6 &\mid 8 + 6\\4 + 4 = 16\ 8 = 4 \times 4 &\mid 4 + 4\\7 + 3 = 21\ 10 = 7 \times 3 &\mid 7 + 3\end{align}$$

Answer (score 8):

The answer would be

> 2110

Because

> $$5\times3 = 15,\quad 5+3 = 8 \implies 158\\9 + 1 \implies 9 \times 1 = 9, \quad 9 + 1 = 10 \implies 910\\8 + 6 \implies 8 \times 6 = 48, \quad 8 + 6 = 14 \implies 4814$$
>  etc.

To explain a bit more

> The answer to the questions is the product followed by the sum of the two numbers, so $(x\times y)(x+y)$ where the brackets are not multiplied but written next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is 2110 because

$5\times3=15$, $5+3=8$, so it becomes $158$
$9\times1=9$, $9+1=10$, so it becomes $910$

It is also the same for $7\times3$